# Is it possible to view the console for a URL loaded into a React Native WebView?

Tags: javascript, react-native, webview, react-native-ios

I have a simple website that loads a URL into a WebView.

The website I load then loads another external website which in one instance is generating an error. I need to see what JavaScript errors are being generated by this website.

I've tried using the Debugger but this just seems to debug the WebView itself rather than what's inside it.

Is it possible to debug/view the console for the website that is inside the WebView?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the only way to do this is the connect the debugger to Safari and then you can see the console in Safari as if you were debugging a normal mobile site.

Comment: can you clarify how to connect the debugger to safari i search the entire internet and couldn't find the answer